# IE CSS ::after pseudo-element issues

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element

I'm having some issues with getting the ::after pseudo-element to behave correctly in IE, even in IE 11.  Here is a screenshot of what is happening: [image: IE fail].

Here is the generated HTML markup from the platform I am using:

```
<div id="ball_iTFXLJGhNGkSyZz7wC7TqMQ" class="ixp-grid-row ixp-container">
    <div id="ball_iIOjpOAQRhkOs4ZMQgPuAEA" class="ixp-grid-col-xs-4 form-navstep-container ixp-container">
        <div id="ball_iFrNaRsKeUCjzJGK9yG3MA" style="float:right;" class="form-navstep-circle active ixp-text">
            <div>1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ball_iHGz8UVJgs0uxaJNLiTwPw" class="ixp-grid-col-xs-4 form-navstep-container ixp-container">
        <div id="ball_ijKJG8GfEykmaCLAbiVidA" style="margin: 0 auto;" class="form-navstep-circle ixp-text">
            <div>2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ball_iNfAak0kgakCYT7Mz4WTuA" class="ixp-grid-col-xs-4 form-navstep-container ixp-container">
        <div id="ball_iHRb3RfKneESxoPOMJXKjmg" class="form-navstep-circle ixp-text">
            <div>3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.form-navstep-container:not(:last-child) .form-navstep-circle:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    height: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.form-navstep-circle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.form-navstep-circle.active {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000; /* For IE 9 and below */
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

This draws the white lines after the numbered steps.  This same issue occurs in older versions of Opera, Chrome, and of course IE.  Firefox manages to handle this all the way back to 5.0.  I thought maybe it was an issue with box-sizing, but despite trying this, the issue has not been resolved in IE.  I also have tried using IE specific stylesheets but due to a limitation in the platform that I am using to create landing pages, I cannot load external stylesheets that aren't meant for the framework before the platform loads.  I am thinking that this issue is relatively easy to fix but I seem to blanking.  If anyone could help me out that would be great.

Here is the link to the staging site: http://info.nlcloans.com/general-public-version-one.

Comment: The padding on the column needed to be removed when I attempted this awhile back. This is using Bootstrap. You really ought to post all of the css for the section, since it wasn't the after element that was my problem, it was the padding of the containing column. http://jsbin.com/buyoya/9/edit

Comment: @BootstrapThemer Thanks for your example I think you may be right about it being an issue with the containing column, so I'm checking it out right now.  The platform I am using, Ion Interactive, uses its own Bootstrap grid replacement classes and I didn't see any padding on it, but I'll continue debugging and see what I can find.  See the link to the actual site above.